# Regex accepting all strings, wronly

Tags: c#, regex, match

I am trying to substrings if they have certain format. Substring Regex query is `[CENAOD(xyx)]`. I have done following code but when running this in cycle it says all results match which is wrong. Where I've done something wrong?

```
string strRegex = @"(\[CENAOD\((\S|\W)*\)\])*";
string strCenaOd = sReader["intro"].ToString()
if (Regex.IsMatch(strCenaOd, strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
      string = (want to read content of ( ) = xyz in example)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Kent's and @leppie's answers, the code surrounding the regex needs work, too.  I think this is what you were trying for:

```
string strRegex = @"\[CENAOD\(([^)]*)\)\]";
string strCenaOd = sReader["intro"].ToString();
Match m = Regex.Match(strCenaOd, strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{
  string content = m.Groups[1];
  // ...
}
```

`IsMatch()` is a simple yes-or-no check, it doesn't provide any way to retrieve the matched text.

I especially want to comment on `(\S|\W)*`, from your regex.  First, `\S|\W` is a very inefficient way to match any character.  `.` is usually all you need, but as Kent pointed out, `[^)]` (i.e., any character except `)`) is more appropriate in this case.  Also, by placing the `*` outside the round brackets, you'll only ever capture the last character.  `([^)]*)` captures all of them.  For more details, [read this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the outer `( ... )*`.

That says no match is a good match too.

Or use `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

if you said **"all strings"**, how about:

```
\[CENAOD\([^\)]*\)\]
```